# Descargar archivo desde una url con un blob

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Me encuentro con la siguiente problemática. Tengo una API que me retorna un JSON con una clave donde viene una url del tipo `blob` la cual contiene un archivo en formato `.xls` (excel).

Este archivo debo manejar lo desde el `controller` de mi aplicación cliente para que cuando el usuario pulse en el botón descargar del front end de la app se gatille dicho controlador para ejecutar una acción de descarga.

Tengo lo siguiente en C#

```
[HttpPost]
public FileResult Download()
{
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("https://miurl.blob.core.windows.net/tmpexcel/Report201906212354.xls");
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
    return new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
}
```

Probé con este código para poder descargarlo pero no me funciono, me dio un error en la parte de convertir la url en byte.

Después probé usando el método `FIle()` pero tampoco me funciono.

¿Quien sabe como lo puedo lograr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finalmente pude resolver mi problema de la siguiente forma:

> Espero que esta respuesta le sirva a alguien más.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<FileResult> DownloadAsync()
    {
        UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder()
        {
            Scheme = "https",
            Host = "midominio.blob.core.windows.net",
            Path = "tmpexcel/Report201906212354.xls"
        };

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var resp = await client.GetAsync(uriBuilder.ToString());
            var content = resp.Content as StreamContent;
            var stream = await content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        }
    }
```

Tambien en vez de crear una nueva url instanciando el objeto `UriBuilder` se puede colocar la url misma directamente en el `await client.GetAsync("miUrl");`

Para asignar un nuevo nombre al archivo se usaria la propiedad `FileDownloadName` de la siguiente forma.

```
return new FileStreamResult(stream, "application/vnd.ms-excel") { FileDownloadName = "MyNameFile" + ".xls" };
```